# readdir_r going into infinite loop for long file names

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I have a fat32 usb drive with following directory structure :

```
/media/pendrive/
├── a
│   ├── 1.mp4
│   ├── 2.mp4
│   └── 3.mp4
└── Data
    ├── files
    │   └── file.txt
    └── 千千千千刻千千千千刻千刻千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千阙歌陈慧娴啊深刻千千千阙千歌陈慧娴啊.mp3

3 directories, 5 files
```

My following program is to read the directory entries :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int count_files(char *path)
{
    int sum = 0;
    DIR *dir;

    dir = opendir(path);
    if (!dir) {
        perror("opendir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (;;) {
        struct dirent entry;
        struct dirent *result;
        char *name;
        char sub_path[256];

        int error = readdir_r(dir, &entry, &result);

        if(error == 36) //36 = ENAMETOOLONG
        {
            printf("Ignoring current file, name too long\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (error != 0) {
            printf("error code : %d\n", error);
            perror("readdir");
        }

        // readdir_r returns NULL in *result if the end
        // of the directory stream is reached
        if (result == NULL)
        {
            printf("NULL returned\n");
            break;
        }

        name = result->d_name;
        if ((strcmp(name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(name, "..") == 0))
            continue;
        printf("%s\n",name);
        sum++;
        if (result->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            sprintf(sub_path, "%s/%s", path, name);
            sum += count_files(sub_path);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    char *path = "/media/pendrive";
    int sum = count_files(path);
    printf("There are %d files in '%s'\n", sum, path);
    return 0;
}
```

This is going into infinite loop :

```
Data
files
file.txt
NULL returned
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
Ignoring current file, name too long
.
.
.
```

How can i handle such case so that i skip the long filename files and move to the next file?

Comment: My quick reading of [the manual page for `readdir_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir_r) didn't say that it's possible to recover from errors, so I guess you're out of luck with that approach. Also it seems the error in question is a GNU extension?

Comment: Following patch fixes the issue but it has not been merged/released with `glibc/readdir_r` implementation. Because the specification  does not mention `ENAMETOOLONG` as a possible error return. https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2013-05/msg00445.html

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should check `errno` (or use function that does, like `perror`) *directly* after the failed function, because you don't know if `errno` will be modified by the code in between. Also, [`readdir_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) isn't actually specified to set `errno`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This code isn't using `errno`, it uses `error` which captures the return value of `readdir_r()`.

Comment: @unwind It does use `perror` if `error` is not `36` or `0`, and as you know `perror` uses `errno`.

Comment: Does that mean `readdir_r` is a disaster? It will get stuck, the moment it encounters a long file name? I think there has to be a way to go past that culprit file. some hack?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding `36` instead of using `ENAMETOOLONG`?

Comment: @deimus : That fix is to send ENAMETOOLONG error and i am already getting the error code.

Comment: Have you determined the max file name length for a fat32 file system yet?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg True ... All the code before that is just doing`if`s on `error`, which should be safe, though.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), I see two potential issues with your code:

First:

> Currently, only some filesystems (among them: Btrfs, ext2, ext3, and
>          ext4) have full support for returning the file type in d_type.  All
>          applications must properly handle a return of DT_UNKNOWN.

Your code does not handle `DT_UNKNOWN`.

Also, what does `pathconf( path, _PC_NAME_MAX )` return for that directory?  Again per the man page:

> Since POSIX.1 does not specify the size of the d_name field, and
>          other nonstandard fields may precede that field within the dirent
>          structure, portable applications that use readdir_r() should allocate
>          the buffer whose address is passed in entry as follows:
>
> ```
>    name_max = pathconf(dirpath, _PC_NAME_MAX);
>    if (name_max == -1)         /* Limit not defined, or error */
>        name_max = 255;         /* Take a guess */
>    len = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + name_max + 1;
>    entryp = malloc(len);
> ```
>
> (POSIX.1 requires that d_name is the last field in a struct dirent.)

Additionally, this is a potential buffer overrun:

```
    char sub_path[256];
    ...
        sprintf(sub_path, "%s/%s", path, name);
```